# Converting product of exponentials from base frame to end-effector frame

Tags: forward-kinematics, product-of-exponentials, screw-theory

This is a homework question from edx course [Robot Mechanics and Control, Part II](https://courses.edx.org/courses/SNUx/SNU446.345.2x/2T2014/course/)

Given the following
[image: Figure]
and expressing its forward kinematics as $T = e^{[S_1]\theta_1} ... e^{[S_6]\theta_6}M$

It is can be found (and also shown in the answer) that

$$ [S_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -2L \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ and
$$ M = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 3L \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -2L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Part 4b) requires expressing the forward kinematics in the form of $T = Me^{[B_1]\theta_1} ... e^{[B_n]\theta_n}$ and finding $[B_2]$

I wanted to try deriving the answer using the following property (as found in the [lecture notes](http://robotics.snu.ac.kr/edX/2014-1/lecturenotes/SNUx_Chapter_5.pdf) page 20 and in the [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AMX59sex4M) around 3:00, basically using property $Pe^A = e^{PAP^{-1}}P$ for any invertible $P$):

$$e^{[S_1]\theta_1} ... e^{[S_n]\theta_n}M = Me^{[B_1]\theta_1} ... e^{[B_n]\theta_n}$$ where $$[B_i] = M^{-1}[S_i]M$$

I get
$$ M^{-1} = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & -3L \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -2L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Using the property $$[B_i] = M^{-1} [S_i] M$$ to calculate $B_2$ and I get
$$
[B_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & -3L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & -5L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

which is obviously wrong.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

The correct answer is

$$ 
[B_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & -3L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Full question with answers below:
[image: Full question]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Woofas. The last section of your image post gives an explanation of how/why the $B_2$ matrix was calculated using *their* method. You posted a procedure - $[B_i]=M^{−1}[S_i]M$ - could you please link to a derivation of that property? I suspect that's where your problem is. I would imagine that there's another step in the procedure, like a summation, or a multiplication, etc., but I can't personally find any details on the step you posted. Please *edit your question* to include the link to the procedure.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, I've attached the source (lecture notes and lecture) for said equation.  Hope it helps you help me!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chuck Sorry it's been a while, but would I be able to provide any more information that may help you help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found my mistake...

The mistake was in the matrix form of the screw

$ [S_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -2L \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$ 
should be 
$ [S_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -2L \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

and I misinterpreted the answer...

$
[B_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & -3L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$
should be 
$ 
[B_2] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & -3L \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

What a fool...